# How to extrude unconnected

Tags: modeling, shortcut, selection-tools, extrude

I want to extrude outward without the faces being connected together in order to get a pattern that looks kind of ribbed (picture for reference) without extruding each face individually.

[image]

This is what I have right now.

[image]

I want all of them to look like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Place your object in *Edit* mode.
- Select all of the faces you want to extrude.

[image: Faces to extrude]

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>F</kbd> to bring up the face context menu.
- Select *Extrude Individual Faces*

  [image: Face context menu with Extrude Individual faces selected]
- Extrude to the distance you want.

  [image: Extruded faces]
- Change the Transform Pivot point to *Individual Origins*

  [image: Setting the transform pivot]
- Scale appropriately.  In my example, I would scale X and Y separately for better control.

  [image: Scaled image]
- Reset the transform pivot point to your usual value.